# Python Pandas shows all text columns as NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have series of a tab separated files that I wish to read in a python script. For some reason when I import the file all of my text columns come back as NaN.

Sample of an input file:

```
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
Period: Oct 28 2013 - Apr 27 2014
Note:
Brand Variant                               Industry                                    Major Category                              Market                                      Media Type                                  Parent Company                              Product Category                            Report Period (multiple)                    PCC Sub Group                               Subsidiary                                  Units   $$$ (000)
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY  CONFECT., SNACKS & SOFT DRINKS  CONFECTIONERY & SNACKS  Columbus Combo  Local Newspaper     COTTAGE FOOD PRODUCTION OPERATION   CANDY   11/18/13 - 11/24/13     F211 CANDY & GUM    COTTAGE FOOD PRODUCTION OPERATION   1   0.286   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR  CONFECT., SNACKS & SOFT DRINKS  CONFECTIONERY & SNACKS  Atlanta Combo   Spot Radio  MARS INC    CANDY BAR   11/04/13 - 11/10/13     F211 CANDY & GUM    MARS SNACKFOOD US LLC   22  1.403
```

Here is a snippet of my python (3.3):

```
df = read_csv(csvFile, delimiter='\t', header=[9])
print(df)
```

Outputs the Following:

```
Brand Variant                             \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Industry                                  \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Major Category                            \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Market                                    \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Media Type                                \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Parent Company                            \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Product Category                          \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Report Period (multiple)                  \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    PCC Sub Group                             \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Subsidiary                                \
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY                                       NaN   
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                                                   NaN   

                                    Units $$$ (000)  
3 LADIES HAND-DIPPED CANDIES CANDY    NaN       NaN  
3 MUSKETEERS CANDY BAR                NaN       NaN
```

I've noticed that my first column seems to be set as the index for the dataframe, however index_col = False will only yield a ValueError as it wants a column number. Likewise I've tried setting the dtype to str but no luck. Lastly, on a different file that was comma separated I was able to get back rows with text data in them. I'm at a lost as to what to do...

One thing I do notice is that between fields its more like tab & space.

Comment: by default `index_col=None` so you shouldn't need to specify, does `df = read_csv(csvFile, delimiter='\s+', header=[9])` work?

Comment: @EdChum, I think `index_col=None` is not the same as `index_col=False`

Comment: @Happy001 they may not be the same but the docs state the default is `None` which is what the OP is intending and unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore the first few lines of "Blah Blah", use `skiprows=` instead of `header=`. Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, sep='\t', skiprows=9, index_col=False)
```

The reason why

> "first column seems to be set as the index for the dataframe"

is, I guess, your file has trailing delimiters. If this is the case, `index_col=False` should help. See [Handling of trailing delimiters in read_csv](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2442)

Since I don't have your input file and your copy-pasted text apparently destroyed tabs (all spaces in text), I can't test it. But please let us know.

Comment: Thanks, your idea of using skiprows seemed to help when the pd.read_csv() tries to auto-assign the dtype. Also after I did the skiprows I was able to finally use index_col=False.

Comment: Here is the final code in case someone else comes across this post. `df = read_csv(csvFile, delimiter='\t', skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], index_col=False)`